# Can connect to docker container when it runs apache, but not when it runs netcat on port 80

Tags: docker

I am running a Debian server (stable), with the `docker.io` Debian package.This is the one distributed by Debian, not the one from the Docker developers. Since `docker.io` is only available in sid, I have installed from there (`apt install -t unstable docker.io`).

My firewall does allow connections to/from docker containers:

```
$ sudo ufw status
(...)
Anywhere                   ALLOW       172.17.0.0/16             
172.17.0.0/16              ALLOW       Anywhere
```

I also have this in `/etc/ufw/before.rules` :

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16    -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So -- I have created an image with

```
$ sudo debootstrap stable ./stable-chroot http://deb.debian.org/debian > /dev/null
$ sudo tar -C stable-chroot -c . | docker import - debian-stable
```

Then started a container and installed apache2 and netcat. Port 1111 on the host machine will be redirected to port 80 on the container:

```
$ docker run -ti -p 1111:80 debian-stable bash
root@dc4996de9fe6:/# apt update
(... usual output from apt update ...)
root@dc4996de9fe6:/# apt install apache2 netcat
(... expected output, installation successful ...)
root@dc4996de9fe6:/# service apache2 start
root@dc4996de9fe6:/# service apache2 status
[ ok ] apache2 is running.
```

And from the host machine I can connect to the apache server:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:1111
(... HTML from the Debian apache placeholder page ...)
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 1111
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

And it waits for me to type (if I type `GET /` I get the Debian apache placeholder page). Ok. And if I stop apache inside the container,

```
root@06da401a5724:/# service apache2 stop
[ ok ] Stopping Apache httpd web server: apache2.
root@06da401a5724:/# service apache2 status
[FAIL] apache2 is not running ... failed!
```

Then connections to port 1111 on the host will be rejected (as expected):

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 1111
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Now, if I start netcat on the container, listening on port 80:

```
root@06da401a5724:/# nc -l 172.17.0.2 80
```

Then I cannot connect from the host!

```
$ telnet localhost 1111
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The same happens if I try `nc -l 127.0.0.1 80` in the container.

What could be happening? Both apache and netcat were listening on port 80. What have I missed?
I'd appreciate any hints...

**update**: if I try this:

```
root@12b8fd142e00:/# nc -vv -l -p 80
listening on [any] 80 ...
172.17.0.1: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
invalid connection to [172.17.0.2] from (UNKNOWN) [172.17.0.1] 54876
```

Then it works!

Now it's weird... `ifconfig` inside the container tells me it has IP `172.17.0.2`, but I can only use netcat binding to `172.17.0.1`:

```
root@12b8fd142e00:/# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

And Apache seems to want to `172.17.0.2` instead:

```
2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

but it actually uses `172.17.0.1`:

```
root@12b8fd142e00:/# netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 12b8fd142e00:http       172.17.0.1:54942        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 12b8fd142e00:39528      151.101.48.204:http     TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: Could you have a try in docker container with 
nc -vv -l -p 80

To have more detail, and be sure to listen on the right IP

Comment: Thank you! I believe that was it. Although `ip` and `ifconfig` inside the container tell me its IP is `172.17.0.2`, apache listens on `172.17.0.1`, and netcat works when listening on `172.17.0.1` too. But  I still don't see why the reported IP is different from the one programs should actually use inside the container...

Comment: And I also don't know why there's that line with `151.101.48.204:http` in the output from `netstat`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is not listening on `172.17.0.1`, that's the address of the host (in the docker bridge).

In the netstat output, the local address has been resolved to `12b8fd142e00`. Use the `-n` option with netstat to see unresolved (numeric) addresses (for example `netstat -plnet` to see listening sockets). `172.17.0.1` is the foreign address that connected to Apache (an it's indeed the host).

The last line in the netstat output shows that some process made a connection to 151.101.48.204:80, probably to make an HTTP request. You can see the PID/name of the process with `netstat -p`.